# Взять текст из div с помощью js

Tags: javascript, html

Собственно есть стандартная ф-ция get запроса на сервер при загрузке страницы, которая из xml файла дергает курсы валют и записывает их на страницу.

```
        function myFunction(xml) {
        var xmlDoc, usd, eur; 
        xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
        usd = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("USD");
        eur = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("EUR");
        usdsel = usd[0].attributes[0].nodeValue;
        usdbuy = usd[0].attributes[1].nodeValue;
        eursel = eur[0].attributes[0].nodeValue;
        eurbuy = eur[0].attributes[1].nodeValue;
        document.getElementById("usdsel").innerHTML = usdsel;
        document.getElementById("usdbuy").innerHTML = usdbuy;
        document.getElementById("eursel").innerHTML = eursel;
        document.getElementById("eurbuy").innerHTML = eurbuy;
    }
```

Так же на странице есть конвертер валют, в котором хотелось бы использовать эти данные, но вот как взять то что скажем я положил в `document.getElementById("usdsel").innerHTML = usdsel;` - получается вот такая конструкция `<div id="usdsel">67.50</div>` Но вот взять эти цифры для дольнейшего использования я не могу 
не так `document.getElementById("usdsel").innerHTML;//пустая строка` не так `document.getElementById("usdsel").nodeValue; //null` `document.getElementById("usdsel").firstChild; //null`
При этом что если просто вставлю левый див, то из него я покойно могу взять текст, видимо что то с очередностью загрузки скрипта? Первая ф-ция заключена в теги head, а взять значения валюты я уже пытаюсь перед , И ещё - разбивка xml файла в хэдере, идет по вызову ф-ции `$(document).ready(function(){})` а взять текст из дива по onclick.

**UPDATE**
https://jsfiddle.net/sopy61z9/1/

Comment: я не совсем понял, сама функция выполняется в head? Если да, то body и все его потомки не определены в это время, соответственно document.getElementById("usdsel") вернет null, а document.getElementById("usdsel").innerHTML вызовет ошибку.

Comment: @Cladoxylon ф-ция myFunction выполняется в head, а document.getElementById("usdsel").innerHTML выполняется в body

Comment: _"ф-ция myFunction выполняется в head"_ -- перенесите ее в конец страницы и поставьте ее до </body>

Comment: ну раз myFunction выполняется в head, то какие могут быть вопросы? В этот момент body ещё нет, а значит и нет `div#usdsel`, `div#usdbuy`, `div#eursel`, `div#eurbuy`. Вставь скрипт перед закрывающим тегом </body>

Comment: функция _myFunction_ выполняется тогда, когда придет ответ AJAX запроса. А значения вы пытаетесь смотреть, не дожидаясь этого.

Comment: [аналогичный вопрос на английском](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, переставил get запрос в тег body и все заработатло

Comment: Что такое `htm`? Подозреваю, что имелся в виду `html`. Если это не так, то объясните, пожалуйста, что это.

Answer (score 2):

Во всех браузерах, кроме FF, есть innerText -- посмотрите на [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/html/). Вместо innerText надо использовать textContent.

```js
var e = document.getElementById("usdsel");
var txt = e.textContent || e.innerText;
alert(txt);
```

```html
<div id="usdsel">67.50</div>
```

Comment: тоже выдает null.. Тут видимо что то надо меня в последовательности загрузки страницы

Comment: нажали на кнопку [выполнить код] и выдает null?

Comment: С кодом все нормально. Ровно такой же пример я удалил.

Comment: null или пустую строку? Это разные вещи

Comment: null или пустую строку? - не знаю, смотрю в консоле FF - тма написано null

Comment: @ГошкаТарасов, неудивительно, что не работает, `.innerText` - нестандартная штука

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id='usdsel'></div>
<script>
  document.getElementById("usdsel").innerText = '33.6';
  var t = document.getElementById("usdsel").innerText;
  console.log(t);
</script>
```

Для чистоты эксперимента добавляю текст в пустой div. Потом читаю его и вывожу в лог.

Все работает корректно. Что говорит консоль в вашем случае?

Comment: _"Все работает корректно"_ -- не может быть. в innetText - t лишнее, должно быть innerText

Comment: Опечатку поправил. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по последней строке, у вас подключена библиотека Jquery/

Можете взять значение `$('#usdsel').text();`

Answer (score 0):

#### Неправильно!

Не используйте `.innerText` - это [нестандартное](http://caniuse.com/#search=innerText) свойство, чья-то выдумка, поддерживаемая некоторыми браузерами.

#### Правильно!

1. Используйте [`textContent`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_textcontent.asp)!
   Для получения текстового содержимого узла консорциум W3C ввел свойство `.textContent`. Поддержка - IE 8+ и **ВСЕ** остальные браузеры. О поддержке см. [тут](http://caniuse.com/#search=textContent)

   **Код:**

   ```
   usdsel.textContent
   //или
   document.querySelector("#usdsel").textContent
   ```
2. Или используйте `.text()` из библиотеки JQuery, как в соседнем ответе советует [Dmitry OnGamer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/477921/189732)

   **Код:**

   ```
   $('#usdsel').text();
   ```

---

P.S: W3C - (WWW Consorcium) организация, разрабатывающая стандарты для Интернета. [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com) - их "школа", где простым языком, с примерами, руководствами объясняется суть разработанных стандартов - что есть и для чего это использовать. Ориентируйтесь на них, если не хотите писать нестандартный (нерабочий) код.

Comment: не стандартное, но поддерживается _всеми_ браузерами кроме firefox <45 версии :)

Comment: @Grundy, где гарантия, что оно внезапно не станет неподдерживаемым?) И вдобавок, 1) лучше привыкать к стандартам, это дисциплинирует, 2) спасает от заминированного кода, 3) объяснений клентам, что это "не наша компания облажалась, это у вас браузер неправильный" и поиска версии браузера, подходящей под текущую коллекцию багов нашего кода)

Comment: стандарты они ведь тоже меняются :-)

Comment: _"поддерживаемая некоторыми браузерами."_ -- не некоторыми, а **всеми браузерами кроме FF** http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/html/

Comment: @Stack, ваша правка что-то меняет? В любом случае 15-20% веб-аудитории (~доля FF) не перестанут видеть глючащий сайт

Comment: @MiKeBu _"ваша правка что-то меняет?"_ -- добавил `e.textContent || e.innerText` -- хотите сказать, что мой textContent хуже чем ваш textContent?)

Comment: @Stack, дополнение в [комментарие](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477914/%d0%92%d0%b7%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-div-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-js/478490#comment546662_478490) - не меняет, а правку в вашем ответе - одобряю. JQuery работает по этому же принципу.

Comment: jQuery не использует innerText из-за несоответствия его поведения поведению, ожидаемому от textContent. Там делается рекурсивный обход узлов, если textContent не оказалось.

Comment: @Grundy, а зачем в FF45 его добавили? о_О

Comment: @Qwertiy, скорее всего для поддержки уже написанных сайтов которые используют это свойство :-) а так вообще не знаю :-) надо к добавляльщикам обращаться :)

Comment: @Grundy, багу, на который они сослались больше 11 лет. Откуда бы вдруг теперь появиться сайтам, которые им понадобится поддерживать? А откуда вдруг откопалась [outerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/outerText), я вообще не понимаю. Тем более, с неизвестной поддержкой по всем браузерам, в том числе FF.

Comment: @Qwertiy, у него еще и поведение очевидное :-D _**Node.outerText** is a nonstandard property. As a getter, it returns the same value as Node.innerText. As a setter, it removes the current node and replaces it with the given text._